# stripe pricing table change the redirect url to our application payment page instead of redirecting it to the stipe's checkout page

Tags: python, flask, stripe-payments

I was using stripe pricing table but when the customer clicks on subscription for a particular plan on the pricing table it redirect's the customer to the checkout page but,I want it to redirect it to my appliction payment page instead of the stripe checkout page,
can this be done in stripe or is there any other way i can proceed?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Stripe Pricing Table can only create Stripe Checkout Sessions. If you want a pricing table to send customers to your own checkout flow you will need to implement it yourself.

Comment: while creating the on-off invoice can we charge the prorated amount to the customer, this is when i want to modify my subscription upgrade process to ensure that customers pay for the new subscription before being upgraded to it? 
@vanya